# Context has been disposed. Execute Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, action-filter

There is a problem with async executing query to web api using entity framework.
General view such that a request is sent to API and ActionFilter catch request to function of controller, send to client status ok with response key, execute request async and after send data by SignalR.
**ActionFilter** starts async executing like this:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (ct) =>
{
    var response = await actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext.ControllerContext,
    actionContext.ActionArguments, ct);
    var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
    await connectionContext.Connection.Send(connectionId, $"{requestKey};{data}");
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public ICollection<TradeAccountModel> GetAll()
{
    using (var ls = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        return _tradeAccountService.GetAll();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public ICollection<TradeAccountModel> GetAll()
{
    using (_tradeAccountRepository.BeginTransaction())
    {
        return _tradeAccountRepository.Get().Select(acc => acc.ToModel());
    }
}
```

**Respository** uses UOW pattern. 
And when repository try to get data from DB there is error: **System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.**

**TDataRepository** containts common operations and extends BaseDataRespository, such as GetById and ect

```
public interface ITradeRepository: ITDataRepository<TradeAccount>
{
}

internal class TradeRepository : T1DataRepository<TradeAccount>,
    ITradeRepository
{

}



IEnumerable<TEntity> ITDataRepository<TEntity>.Get()
    {
        return base.Get<TEntity>();
    }
```

**BaseDataRespository** has BeginTransaction method

```
public IDisposable BeginTransaction()
    {
        if (_scope == null)
        {
            _scope = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions()
                {
                    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300)
                },
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
        }

        return _scope;
    }
```

Context creates by BaseDataRespository

```
private TransactionScope _scope;
    private readonly Lazy<DataContext> _contextFactory;

    private DataContext Context => _contextFactory.Value;

    public BaseDataRepository()
    {
        _contextFactory = new Lazy<DataContext>(()=> 
        {
            var ctx = CreateContext();

            ctx.FireBuild += Build;

            return ctx;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `_tradeAccountRepository`?

Comment: Yep, I have been edited post

Comment: I don't get why you need to use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. And probabily it is causing the exception you get. Because you are in a action filter and you are trying to execute action result manullay but by the time BackgroundWorker runs your code that action might already been completed.

Comment: I was gonna ask the same question as @Eldar asked. Are you executing another action from action filter?

Comment: Because there are a lot of requests and they take a long time to calculate

Comment: You don't need to execute it manually. There is an overridable method that executes after action execution you can get the result there and pass it through your connection.

Comment: @weichch no it's same
I just start it asynchronously, return the status OK to the client, and then return the data using SignalR to the Client

Comment: Background tasks **do not** have scope required by a request. If you run a request from background task, you have to set the scope up. If your background task accidentally caught a service belongs to the current request, the service could have been disposed by the time the task runs.

Comment: @weichch Ok, If I will not use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem, how I can run request async?

Comment: You do not need to call a controller action since you have had a service layer. What you can do is creating a new lifetime scope off the root container in your background task, and resolve your service layer using the new lifetime scope. Then call the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `DbContext` is registered as scoped service / HTTP request scoped service, you should refrain from passing `DbContext` from your request pipeline to your background task.

This is because as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8):

> Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request.

Any scoped services that also implement `IDisposable` will be automatically disposed after the request completes.

You should activate new `DbContext` using an independent scope in your controller action / request pipeline, and pass it to your background task.

This [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) is for .Net Core, but it may give you ideas how scoped services could be used in a background task.